# Why can questions with accepted answers be deleted?

Tags: discussion

I answered a question on Stack Overflow and had an upvote and was an accepted answer. I then log in later and what was +25 reputation points is now gone.

I know it's probably not a big deal people with a lot of reputation points, but when you're new it really stings. If the user determined that the answer was what he/she wanted, I feel like it should not be able to be deleted.

Comment: Bad content is deletable and is a question is bad, then it can/will be deleted, no matter if it has an accepted answer or not. If you want to avoid such reputation lost in the future, then try to concentrate your time on good questions, which deserve it.

Comment: I would guess the question was off topic and answering it does not make it on topic. What would be the point of a sites focus, if off topic questions could stay just because someone answerd? We hyave all been here and the solution is simple, do your best not to answer off topic/bad questions, then they won.t get removed.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange focus on content, and the main goal is to have good quality content.

The judges of what is good and what is not good are the site users, each site of the network and its own set of active users with the privilege to vote, close, and delete questions or answers.

When question is found to be off topic, those users can close it, then after it is closed, delete it.

Having accepted answer is not relevant. This is not a personal help forum, so the question author personal opinion does not matter. The question can still be bad and/or off topic.

However, if the question did have answers with positive score, this means people found it helpful after all, and it's worth to flag the deleted question for moderator attention asking to at least undelete it (while leaving it closed), or raise a meta discussion about it in the per-site meta.

Comment: Just curious, I thought we cant delete a question with upvoted answer, does its the 10k delete vote that can bypass that?

Comment: @yagmoth555 what you refer to is the question author who indeed can't delete in such a case.

Comment: @mmyers actually question does not have to have negative score. Any question can be closed, then 10k users can vote to delete after 3 days. 20k users don't even have to wait.